# How to support runtime language change from a React Native application?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am developing a React Native application in which I have already implemented multiple language support from device locale using [react-native-i18n](https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/react-native-i18n) plugin. Now, I want to add runtime language change support from the mobile application itself. I have checked [react-native-localization](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-localization) but there is an open issue saying it does not support language detection from device locale. Is there a way to achieve both functionalities at the same time?

Comment: Found out a solution myself, please refer this link :
http://logicstime.com/how-to-implement-user-selectable-language-settings-for-your-react-native-app/#comment-69

Comment: site down/broken link

Comment: @will Here is the code, I have implemented it using i18n :

  onSelectLanguage() {  
  return(
    language.map((data, i)=>{
   return (
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.onSelectedLang(data)}>
       <Text style={styles.dropDownText}>{data.lang}</Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
    )
   })
   )
  }

    onSelectedLang(text) {
   this.setState({
     showDropDown: false,
     select: text.lang,
   }),   
   i18n.locale = text.code;
    }
    onLanguage() {
   this.setState({
     showDropDown: true,
   })
    }